From where ca I download the gpg signing keys for atareao (e.g. touchpad-indicator) and for giuspen (x-tile)
This question pertains to Xubuntu 22.04 and arose in the preparation for Xubuntu 24.04:
I found
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/atareao-ubuntu-atareao.gpg (belonging to touchpad-indicator) and
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/giuspen-ubuntu-ppa.gpg (belonging to x-tile)
still in the trusted.gpg keyring, which is deprecated.
According to the Debian Instructions to connect to a third-party repository a binary export (gpg --export) of the certificate SHOULD be available at the root of the repository under the filename deriv-archive-keyring.pgp. Does this mean that it is part of the to-be downloaded repository? Or does one have to download the key separately, as I was told elsewhere: preferably from the website of the package maintainers and using a secure connection like https or hkps to be secured against MIM attacks or against a mirror server which serves a manipulated package together with manipulated signing key?
But where do I find those gpg signing keys for touchpad-indicator and for x-tile?
From where for other Launchpad-related software packages?

Contact the makers of the software is a good place to start.

Yes, I found the signing key and the fingerprint for giuspen under the headline "Technical details about this PPA" at https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. It depends on the version of the operating system. Giuspen also gives a single-lined .list file example, but without signed-by=....

Seems like you comment should be uased as the answer in the answer your own question feature. At the bottom of the question you will see the button for the Answer Your Own Question.

The PPA pages will have this information on launchpad - See "Technical details about this PPA"
https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

and from https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao
Use gpg from the commandline to get the keys
$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A98E8BBCABCF6A49A5DA2F43B8668B055FE1EFE4
gpg: key B8668B055FE1EFE4: public key "Launchpad PPA for giuspen" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 24D6ECA2F0503C89698F226025402D509B042DD9
gpg: key 25402D509B042DD9: public key "Launchpad PPA for atareao-team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1


